# Android - use ContactPicker to get a number AND last name?

Tags: android, contacts

It seems straightforward to use the ContactPicker to get the phone number and DISPLAY NAME for a contact - use something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_CONTACT);
```

However, with this you get the phone number and the DISPLAY NAME, but I can't seem to find any sane way to get the last name/first name once I get the number.  The ID for the contact itself does not seem to be available with what is returned from the startActivityForResult.   I guess you could requery based on the display name or number to find the contact, but that seems awkward... I was just thinking there's a more straightforward way, but could be wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The contact picker returns a URI for the contact requested.  You need to requery on this URI and you can get whatever you want.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

  switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT) :
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
         // TODO Whatever you want to do with the selected contact
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks - I was under the assumption that it returns something peculiar to phone numbers here, since the intent was started Phone.CONTENT_URI.  In this case, the picker shows all the numbers of each contact (and only contacts that have phone numbers), and I assumed that the ID in the data.getData() call was associated with the phone number and was not the contact ID. If you use the more general Contacts.CONTENT_URI instead for the intent, the picker shows ALL contacts, whether or not they have a number (which is not what I'm interested in).  I'll recheck some things here based on what you said.